# Write data into cell into one line

Tags: java, export-to-excel, jxl

I am using jxl to export an Excel sheet.
I just need to write data into a cell into just one line without shifting data to a new line into same cell.

Expected at Cell:

```
Hello I am just testing you.
```

Actual:

```
Hello I am 
just testing you.
```

My code:

```
   WritableCellFormat tableDataFormatDefault;

    tableDataFormatDefault = new WritableCellFormat(TABLE_DATA_FONT);
    tableDataFormatDefault.setBorder(Border.ALL, BorderLineStyle.THIN);
    tableDataFormatDefault.setWrap(true);
    tableDataFormatDefault.setAlignment(Alignment.CENTRE);
    tableDataFormatDefault.setWrap(true)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: tableDataFormatDefault.setWrap(true); i think you should set it to false; i have no possibility to test it

Comment: Nothing is changed .. any other ideas !

Comment: You dont need to set the wrap twice. Do you try to adjust the column width?

Comment: Sorry my mistake ... I just removed the 2nd wrap & set the first one to false as you said and it works.

Comment: Thanks Darin and sorry for such silly mistake.

Comment: http://bethecoder.com/applications/tutorials/excel/jexcel-api/how-to-set-excel-column-width.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tableDataFormatDefault.setWrap(false);
```